# Angular really needs to integrate Odata sort, filter etc?

Tags: angular, odata, angular8

I require the clarification from the angular experts here. My client asking me to use the `Odatas` inbuilt function to `filter, sort and paginations` he shared a link as:

[this Odata article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/supercharging-asp-net-core-api-with-odata/)

My question is, when i use the `Odata` in backed, still I can use the font end filter, sort etc using the `angular` data manipulations. But is it worth to use the backend query based filter, sort and pagination using Odata?

Please help me to understand.

Comment: I'm not a fan of reinventing the wheel on the back end to get those things. Hand rolling it (even with the ease of LINQ) when compared to the simplicity of using a provider I'd say it is. Plus, the front end shouldn't be doing too much heavy lifting anyway. Use that stuff for UX.

Comment: I'm going to have to say this is opinion based. This depends on your use case, do you want to return 1000's of data then filter with rxjs? Or do you just want to return smaller result set.